# ScrollBy doesn't work in IE and Chrome when used on any Element Other than window

Tags: javascript

As the title implies I'm trying to scroll the content of a div by 20 pixels when user clicked a button, but it only works in firefox so far.
This is the html :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing Scroll By on Chrome</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        div{
            width:500px;
            height: 500px;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body >
<button onclick="goDown()">Go Down </button>
<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis id ultricies velit. Etiam ut elit viverra, iaculis purus at, sollicitudin quam. Maecenas eget mollis metus. Duis et facilisis eros, ac gravida mi. Duis turpis urna, faucibus quis risus ac, ornare euismod justo. Fusce venenatis lorem in orci sagittis aliquam. Etiam fermentum metus faucibus velit rutrum rutrum.

    Aenean tincidunt auctor tincidunt. Integer in vulputate dui, eget maximus mauris. Cras at libero vehicula, volutpat lectus ac, pulvinar enim. In porttitor leo vel laoreet facilisis. Mauris ultrices justo non lectus maximus, ut blandit augue malesuada. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget turpis pulvinar, iaculis nisl vitae, mattis dui. Vestibulum facilisis posuere libero at venenatis. Vestibulum posuere tempor est, ut pretium ligula sollicitudin viverra. Sed id tellus nibh. Curabitur varius velit nibh, id placerat nunc venenatis eget.

    Vivamus gravida consectetur urna id blandit. Integer mauris felis, dignissim ut risus eget, consequat convallis odio. Donec vitae tristique est, et sollicitudin urna. Nam justo est, bibendum consequat luctus quis, scelerisque eget enim. Morbi lorem ligula, tincidunt ut molestie at, scelerisque et turpis. Sed lacinia dictum pellentesque. Fusce vestibulum, leo ac auctor iaculis, ante magna faucibus nulla, at elementum sem lectus quis tortor. Suspendisse eu dignissim lacus, vel elementum felis. Praesent non molestie ex, et ornare massa.

    Nullam diam lacus, ultrices sed eleifend laoreet, placerat a dolor. Quisque non enim id erat tincidunt fringilla. Integer neque lacus, aliquet id iaculis sed, efficitur ac velit. Etiam felis felis, cursus a massa ac, tincidunt convallis leo. Cras tempor ante laoreet dignissim bibendum. Nullam non auctor turpis. Etiam in est posuere, gravida nulla nec, maximus purus. Fusce non rutrum quam. Pellentesque in orci facilisis, posuere lorem sed, pharetra sem. Quisque malesuada, dui in hendrerit posuere, sem est iaculis justo, sit amet iaculis lectus neque sit amet velit. Etiam vulputate ut diam at aliquet. Nunc ultricies velit non elit vehicula malesuada id a odio.

    Vestibulum vitae gravida lectus. Phasellus bibendum pharetra maximus. Maecenas et velit quis augue tincidunt vehicula. Proin pharetra magna in lectus feugiat, sed hendrerit neque suscipit. Sed pretium aliquam nunc, eu commodo nunc. Mauris quis dui diam. In fringilla leo ut arcu pellentesque elementum sed in metus. Nam maximus diam felis, nec lacinia elit rhoncus sit amet. In maximus, leo eget consequat finibus, augue purus dictum dolor, a sollicitudin risus mauris eu ante. Etiam dapibus interdum ligula ac gravida. Morbi non turpis posuere, volutpat dui sit amet, malesuada tortor. Morbi mollis, ipsum eu vulputate porttitor, enim lacus elementum leo, sed ornare lacus felis ut sapien. Sed lobortis ipsum et dui facilisis, nec consequat nibh gravida. Sed tristique libero eu efficitur pharetra. Donec suscipit consequat nibh a bibendum. Fusce efficitur mi a nibh vestibulum scelerisque.

    In mi velit, facilisis sed tortor vitae, dapibus scelerisque lectus. Quisque laoreet mollis mattis. Proin id mauris euismod dolor suscipit bibendum. Suspendisse ut convallis nisl. Nunc suscipit non ex lobortis rutrum. Suspendisse ornare nibh eu sapien rhoncus molestie. Vestibulum ornare massa feugiat, convallis metus eu, sagittis lorem. Sed nec metus faucibus, iaculis nisi at, pulvinar odio. Ut dignissim ex a elementum hendrerit. Nullam lobortis ultrices quam, id feugiat odio iaculis eu. In in ex elementum, rhoncus sapien sit amet, consectetur est. Aliquam dignissim velit tortor, et porttitor arcu suscipit at. Morbi in dui vel libero feugiat venenatis. 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the javascript :

```
<script>
function goDown(){
  document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].scrollBy(0,20);
}
</script>
```

Is there any solution for it work in Chrome and IE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best possible solution is to use `scrollLeft / scrollTop` properties.

I.e you could say, instead of `elem.scrollBy(0,10)` -->
`elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollTop + 10;`

Alternatively you can stab the `Element.prototype`:

```
Element.prototype.scrollBy = function(x,y) {
  this.scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft + x;
  this.scrollTop = this.scrollTop + y;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

MSIE and Edge still don't support `Element.scrollBy` as of 2019. I've built [element-scroll-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/element-scroll-polyfill) for that reason, a minimal npm package that adds W3C spec compliant `scrollBy`, `scrollTo` and `scroll` methods to `Element` instances.

Alternatively, you can use [smoothscroll-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smoothscroll-polyfill) which provides more functionality but is about twice the size.